# Installing cgal by vcpkg

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, vcpkg

I am trying to install cgal using vcpkg. I didn't have vcpkg before that and installed it through git, so it is my first package (if I understand correctly comment). And I don't know what is bootstrapping process and I didn't try to install another package.

I have this error in the terminal:

```
Error: vcpkg was unable to detect the active compiler's information. See above for the CMake failure output.
```

After running this:

```
./vcpkg.exe install cgal:x64-windows
```

I tried to figure out what CMake is and need I to install it separately. But if I understand correctly, it is installing during this process, because in './vcpkg/downloads' there is 'ZIP-file cmake-3.20.1-windows-i386'.

I need to install this cgal for correct work of some function in Python library, so I do not fully understand what is going on.. I tried to Google this problem but didn't find anything that works. Python library I installed by pip, the library name is gudhi. In logs I have seen this:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Path to what? To compiler? But what is it?

Full logs look like this (I changed paths names because they were too long):

```
[1/1] cmd /c "cd .. && "../Documents/GitHub/vcpkg/downloads/tools/cmake-3.20.1-windows/cmake-3.20.1-windows-i386/bin/cmake.exe" "../Documents/GitHub/vcpkg/scripts/detect_compiler" "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=../Documents/GitHub/vcpkg/downloads/tools/ninja/1.10.1-windows/ninja.exe" "-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON" "-DVCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../Documents/GitHub/vcpkg/scripts/toolchains/windows.cmake" "-DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-windows" "-DVCPKG_SET_CHARSET_FLAG=ON" "-DVCPKG_PLATFORM_TOOLSET=v142" "-DCMAKE_EXPORT_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON" "-DCMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON" "-DCMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_SYSTEM_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_SYSTEM_RUNTIME_LIBS_SKIP=TRUE" "-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON" "-DVCPKG_APPLOCAL_DEPS=OFF" "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../Documents/GitHub/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" "-DCMAKE_ERROR_ON_ABSOLUTE_INSTALL_DESTINATION=ON" "-DVCPKG_CXX_FLAGS=" "-DVCPKG_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=" "-DVCPKG_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG=" "-DVCPKG_C_FLAGS=" "-DVCPKG_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=" "-DVCPKG_C_FLAGS_DEBUG=" "-DVCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE=dynamic" "-DVCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS=" "-DVCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE=" "-DVCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG=" "-DVCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE=x64" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR:STRING=lib" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR:STRING=bin" "-D_VCPKG_ROOT_DIR=../Documents/GitHub/vcpkg" "-D_VCPKG_INSTALLED_DIR=../Documents/GitHub/vcpkg/installed" "-DVCPKG_MANIFEST_INSTALL=OFF" "-G" "Ninja" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../Documents/GitHub/vcpkg/packages/detect_compiler_x64-windows""
FAILED: ../CMakeCache.txt 
cmd /c "cd .. && "../Documents/GitHub/vcpkg/downloads/tools/cmake-3.20.1-windows/cmake-3.20.1-windows-i386/bin/cmake.exe" "../Documents/GitHub/vcpkg/scripts/detect_compiler" "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=../Documents/GitHub/vcpkg/downloads/tools/ninja/1.10.1-windows/ninja.exe" "-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON" "-DVCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../Documents/GitHub/vcpkg/scripts/toolchains/windows.cmake" "-DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-windows" "-DVCPKG_SET_CHARSET_FLAG=ON" "-DVCPKG_PLATFORM_TOOLSET=v142" "-DCMAKE_EXPORT_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON" "-DCMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON" "-DCMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_SYSTEM_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_SYSTEM_RUNTIME_LIBS_SKIP=TRUE" "-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON" "-DVCPKG_APPLOCAL_DEPS=OFF" "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../Documents/GitHub/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" "-DCMAKE_ERROR_ON_ABSOLUTE_INSTALL_DESTINATION=ON" "-DVCPKG_CXX_FLAGS=" "-DVCPKG_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=" "-DVCPKG_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG=" "-DVCPKG_C_FLAGS=" "-DVCPKG_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=" "-DVCPKG_C_FLAGS_DEBUG=" "-DVCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE=dynamic" "-DVCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS=" "-DVCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE=" "-DVCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG=" "-DVCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE=x64" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR:STRING=lib" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR:STRING=bin" "-D_VCPKG_ROOT_DIR=../Documents/GitHub/vcpkg" "-D_VCPKG_INSTALLED_DIR=../Documents/GitHub/vcpkg/installed" "-DVCPKG_MANIFEST_INSTALL=OFF" "-G" "Ninja" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../Documents/GitHub/vcpkg/packages/detect_compiler_x64-windows""
The system cannot find the path specified.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: Are you using msvc with vcpkg? I ask because the default triplet builds using msvc and 32 bit

Comment: @drescherjm msvc installed on my PC but I never used it

Comment: @drescherjm I've added some information about the version if I understand u correctly. Because I tried to install cgal for my x64 windows version

Comment: You aren't saying much about what you did and what happened. Did you already have vcpkg or is this the first package you are trying to install? Did you run the bootstrapping process? Does installing some random other package work? Do you have visual studio installed? Etc. And making the full log available somewhere could also help, instead of just copying 2 lines. Also, doesn't there exist a precompiled version (pip, conda) of your python package? That would make it unnecessary to install CGAL.

Comment: Try running this from a Visual Studio x64 native tools command prompt

Comment: I do agree with @MarcGlisse, it would help if we had these details.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Thank you for the comment! I tried to add information about what you asked (by the way I don't know what is bootstrapping)! I have VS2019 and pip and conda

Comment: @drescherjm I tried to do it through VS cmd prompt but nothing changed(

Comment: From https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg , after `git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg`, there is `.\vcpkg\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat` (that's what I called bootstrapping) before all the `.\vcpkg\vcpkg install stuff`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Yes, I think I did it and after that, I've got an .exe file of vcpkg

Comment: @MarcGlisse But I didn't do it by the console

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are on Windows, and if so, first you need to have the [prerequisites](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg#quick-start-windows) met. Make sure you follow the installation and setup steps as outlined [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg). Second, please try to install it with the option "**--debug**" to get full logs.

Run it from a PowerShell console.

Comment: Thank you!
When I tried to install it, I used these steps yes. I added full logs and additional info in question! Maybe it will be helpful...

Comment: Np! It looks like a cmake path issue. It cannot find that path. [This](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/10066#issuecomment-587094034) offers a solution for a similar problem, if not the same. I strongly recommend that you install vcpkg in the root C directory.